# Geo Nodes: How to calculate tangent of mesh

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I want to align instances along a displaced mesh. The problem is that the (red) instances always point in the same direction no matter where they are positioned. The instances should be aligned to the tangents (or maybe the normals?) of the mesh, so every instance gets the correct rotation. In the Screenshot I drew (green arrows) how I think it should look like.

I know how to calculate the tangent of a CURVE but I don't know how to do this with a mesh. Thank you for your help. I also attached the blend file:

[image]

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: SCreenshot 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

[image]

and to make it "look good" you should move your cone in edit mode, so that the pivot point is at the bottom:

[image]

...because the cone will rotate around that point.

result:

[image]

be aware that the result might look wrong (but it isn't) because you scaled the cones so much, that it might not be clear where the face midpoint is on which the cone is positioning itself.

So if you scale down the cones a bit, a looks "better":

[image]

[image]

Note:

you should do the following: the scale of your object is -12.7807 on XYZ. I would apply the scale with Ctrl+A. Since the scale was negative, you now have to go into Edit Mode and recalculate normals by selecting all faces and pressing Shift+N. Another problem is, you are not instancing the cone object itself but the collection of the cone. So when you for example move the cone it will not stay on the surface. So either instance the object or if you want to keep using the collection, you should enable Separate Children and Reset Children.

Comment: Hmmm... strange: when I try it, I don't need the _Align Euler to Vector_ node. Actually I can simply plug the _Rotation_ output of the _Distribute Points on Faces_ node into the _Rotation_ input of the _Instance on Points_ node. The _Align Euler to Vector_ only works for me if I use the _Rotation_ input instead of the _Vector_ input - then I have to set the _Pivot_ to Z. But the result is the same as I wouldn't use the node at all. Which Blender version are you on at the moment? I'm using 3.2.0

Comment: As you know…the newest alpha - 3.3 

Comment: And doesn't it work there without _Align Euler to Vector_? But apart from that I have to fix so many other things to make the spikes show up... I have to reduce the density of the distribution since my PC doesn't seem to like that many instances, and I have to unplug the scale from the lower node tree etc.

Comment: In my test it didn’t work without align. But as you can see in my node tree I unplugged his rotation and just use that align value…

Comment: Yeah, me too. And I don't know what the scaling is all about, but the last nodes before plugging into the _Scale_ input is first combining XYZ to a Vector only to then plug it in a single value multiply node, where it's multiplied by -0.1 so that it gives a negative scale...?

Comment: Maybe he wanted to mirror the cone? ‍♂️I have no idea what OP wanted to do there…

Comment: I'm foxed! I don't understand why plugging an Euler rotation (Series of angles, around X,Y,Z) into a vector direction (Set of lengths, in X,Y,Z) should work, except by luck :)  So I have to agree with @GordonBrinkmann on this one: as [here](https://imgur.com/a/O2i0O7w)

Comment: @RobinBetts Actually I don't understand it either. Plugging the rotation of the points into the rotation of the instances just seemed logical and it works. I guess you're right, using the rotation as vectors just happened to work by luck. If I inspect it closer they are only almost aligned... anyway, the whole model with negative and unapplied scales and the collection instance is a bit messed up so that I would change a lot of things before dealing with the rotation of the cones ;)

Comment: @Gordon no problem with yours -- rotation to rotation..'face distribute points' must be using 'Euler aligning to face normal' as a sensible default. [This](https://imgur.com/a/FKN96ql) is the one, as posted, (rotation to vector) I don't get.

Comment: @RobinBetts Yes I know, I understood that ;) That's why I said I guess you're right this only worked by luck. And if you inspect it closer you can see that it actually doesn't work... it appears to be working on this uneven surface and with all the scaling issues going on. But if you use the _Align Euler to Vector_ like Chris on a simple geometry like an icosphere, it's definitely not working.